# SSIS Checksum transformation with SCD Type 2

Tags: ssis, checksum, scd2

In SSIS `SCD Type 2` transformation, we can preserve the old historical data.

How can we preserve the historical data using a Checksum transformation?

Comment: _Please dont shout_.. ALL CAPS is shouting

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

All a checksum transformation does is generate a value the relates to the data passing through it.  In order to utilise this value in a Slowly Changing Dimension (the actual table in your database, not the transformation), you would need to use the checksum value within either a `lookup` function or if you have loaded it into a staging environment, via SQL scripts that compare the new checksum with the old checksum when matched on the primary business key of your data row.